# ng-repeat doesn't work on json array

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, angularjs

I have this json array

[
         {
        Company:  {
        id: "19",
        features_id: null,
        features: "a:6:{i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:1:"3";i:4;s:1:"0";i:5;s:1:"0";i:6;s:1:"6";}"
        },
        User: [ ]
        },
-{
        Company:  {
        id: "20",
        features_id: null,
        features: "a:6:{i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:1:"3";i:4;s:1:"4";i:5;s:1:"5";i:6;s:1:"6";}"
        },
        User:  [
         {
        id: "1",
        group_id: "1",
        type: null
        }
        ]
}]

for somereason I cant get data into my div. Anyhelp will be appreciated. here is the jsfidler

http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9L3/

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't help us, sadly, as the URL is relative so we'll never get a response. However, make sure you look up the jQuery AJAX parameters- Include `datatype:'json'` to ensure it's being parsed as JSON.

Comment: hi Dan, thanks. data is like this
[{"Company":{"id":"19","name":"xyz","f_id":null,"features":"a:6:{i:1;s:1:\"1\";i:2;s:1:\"2\";i:3;s:1:\"3\";i:4;s:1:\"0\";i:5;s:1:\"0\";i:6;s:1:\"6\";}"},"User":[]}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That JSON is not valid.  Also, your template is not going to output anything visible unless you put some bind tags in the repeater like {{Company.Company.id}} for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$.ajax()`, so Angular doesn't know about it.

Use `$http` like this http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9L3/5/.